# Mutliple domains in the same httpd.conf

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

I have two domain names that point to the same IP address. One of the domains is hosted locally on the server, the other is just a forward to another domain (we migrated our Confluence to the cloud, but need to keep old links alive)

My httpd.conf looks a little like this (a lot of, hopefully, irrelevant info removed).

```
Listen 80
Listen 443

NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost *:443

<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName esd.domain.com
   Redirect / https://esd.domain.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
   ServerName esd.domain.com
   DocumentRoot "C:/Apache/htdocs"
   SSLEngine On
   SSLCertificateFile "/Apache/conf/esd.domain.com.crt"
   SSLCertificateKeyFile "/Apache/conf/esd.domain.com.key2"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName documentation.domain.com
   Redirect "/display/" "https://domain.atlassian.net/wiki/display/"
   Redirect "/" "https://domain.atlassian.net/"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
   ServerName documentation.domain.com
   Redirect "/display/" "https://domain.atlassian.net/wiki/display/"
   Redirect "/" "https://domain.atlassian.net/"
</VirtualHost>
```

This works great for esd.domain.com, but documentation.domain.com ends up at esd.domain.com as well.

Does anyone have any pointers on how I should be doing this please? I'm an httpd novice who has inherited this system and struggling! Thanks in advance.

This page seems to suggest it's possible: https://docs.jelastic.com/name-based-apache-virtual-host 
The only difference with mine is that the second domain is a redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the issue wasn't with the .conf file, rather that

```
httpd -k restart
```

Wasn't actually restarting due to a permissions problem. It was reporting errors in the .conf file so gave the impression it was restarting, when in fact it wasn't able to shut down the running instance. In the end I found a small error in the log file that the service couldn't be stopped and sorted the permissions out. 
Now the above .conf file works a charm.